# Setting OppurtunityAccessLevel field on Object OpportunityTeamMember using Trigger

Tags: trigger, dmlexception, record-access-level, opportunity-teams

I was doing some case study for learning Triggers and got a requirement like below

- **Once a new Opportunity is added, then the Manager of Opportunity Owner need to be attach in the Opportunity team with 'Sales manager' Role**

I was able to write an After Trigger and working fine without setting  'Opportunity Access Level'.

```
trigger OppTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
    for(Opportunity newOpp:Trigger.new){
            Opportunity uv = [Select ID, Owner.ManagerID from Opportunity where Opportunity.Id = :newOpp.Id Limit 1];
            if(uv.Owner.ManagerId != NULL) {
                OpportunityTeamMember oppTeam    =  new OpportunityTeamMember();
                oppTeam.TeamMemberRole           =  'Sales Manager';
                oppTeam.UserId                   =  uv.Owner.ManagerID;
                //oppTeam.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read Only';
                oppTeam.OpportunityId            = newOpp.Id;
                system.debug(oppTeam);
                insert oppTeam;
            }
    }
}
```

I am getting a run time error as below if I try to set the 'Opportunity Access Level'. But without Trigger and via UI I can set this, can someone help me to understand it better?

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger OppTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: OppTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Opportunity Access:
>   bad value for restricted picklist field: Read Only:
>   [OpportunityAccessLevel]: Trigger.OppTrigger: line 11, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpportunityTeamMember.OpportunityAccessLevel is not a writeable field. You will have to make use of Opportunity Share object to achieve this. Hence you need to use the below mentioned code to provide the access.

```
OpportunityTeamMember oppTeam =  new OpportunityTeamMember();
oppTeam.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Manager';
oppTeam.UserId =  uv.Owner.ManagerID;
oppTeam.OpportunityId = newOpp.Id;
insert oppTeam;

//get all of the team members' sharing records

List<<OpportunityShare> OpportunityShare> shares = [SELECT Id, OpportunityAccessLevel, 
    RowCause FROM OpportunityShare WHERE 
    OpportunityId IN :SomeSetOfOpptyIds AND 
    RowCause = 'Team'];

// set all team members access to read/write
for (OpportunityShare share : shares)  {
    share.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
}
update shares;
```

Also looks like your trigger code is not bulkified one. You will end up with `Too many SOQL queries: 101` governor limit error since you are firing query within for loop which is not at all recommended.

Refer [this link](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/03/17/opportunityaccesslevel-not-writable/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since OpportunityAccessLevel is a Restricted picklist.

> Valid values are: Read, Edit.

For more details on `Read Only is not supported` error, refer [this][1] link.